# R: Creating a Column Based on Values in 2 Columns

Tags: r

I would like to insert column `Coins/Copay` and assign values 1,0 based on 5 conditions:

1. (Plans A, B, C) - `Coins` amount listed but NA `Copay` -> `Coins/Copay` = 1
2. (Plans D, E) - `Copay` amount listed but NA `Coins` -> `Coins/Copay` = 0
3. (Plan F) - `Coins` and `Copay` amounts = 0 -> `Coins/Copay` = 0
4. (Plans G, H) - `Coins` and `Copay` amounts listed, but `Copay` does not = 0 -> `Coins/Copay` = 0
5. (Plans I, J) - `Coins` is greater than `Copay` and `Copay` = 0 -> `Coins/Copay` = 1

With the following dataset:

```
Plans   Coins   Copay
  A       0       NA
  B       0       NA
  C      10       NA
  D      NA        0
  E      NA       50
  F       0        0
  G      20       10
  H      40        5
  I      20        0
  J       5        0
```

I would like the result to be:

```
    Plans   Coins   Copay  Coins/Copay
      A       0       NA        1
      B       0       NA        1
      C      10       NA        1
      D      NA        0        0
      E      NA       50        0
      F       0        0        0
      G      20       10        0
      H      40        5        0
      I      20        0        1
      J       5        0        1
```

Sorry if this is confusing! Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You actually only need to specify the `Coins.Copay == 1` cases, and have the rest default to `0`.

```
 library(tidyverse);
 df %>%
   mutate(Coins.Copay = case_when(
       Plans %in% c("A", "B", "C") & !is.na(Coins) & is.na(Copay) ~ 1,
       Plans %in% c("I", "J") & Coins > Copay & Copay == 0 ~ 1,
       TRUE ~ 0
   ))
#   Plans Coins Copay Coins.Copay
#1      A     0    NA           1
#2      B     0    NA           1
#3      C    10    NA           1
#4      D    NA     0           0
#5      E    NA    50           0
#6      F     0     0           0
#7      G    20    10           0
#8      H    40     5           0
#9      I    20     0           1
#10     J     5     0           1
```

Comment: Quick question - this is just an example of a much larger data set. I am just a beginner to R and am confused about "c("A", "B", "C")"; I am trying to apply these conditions to the entire dataset, but from my very limited knowledge, I am led to believe this condition is only being applied specifically to Plans A,B,C. Am I understanding this correctly? If not, do I just pick 3 plans that fit the criteria described above?

Comment: @BirdBirdBird `Plans %in% c("A", "B", "C")` returns `TRUE` if `Plans` is either `"A"`, `"B"` or `"C"`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately I am still having trouble applying the function. When I use what you posted above, the result is all 0s with only "A", "B", "C", "I", "J" returning 1s. Would you happen to know why this might be?

Comment: @BirdBirdBird ??? But that is exactly the same as the expected output you posted! If you're minimal data are not representative (enough) of your actual problem, the data are *not representative* and you need to think about how you can change that. Is that the issue? Please don't open another question. This is very much frowned upon here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```
df$`Coins/Copay` <- case_when(
    df$Plans %in% c('A', 'B', 'C') & !is.na(df$Coins) & is.na(df$Copay) ~ 1,
    df$Plans %in% c('D', 'E') & is.na(df$Coins) & !is.na(df$Copay) ~ 0,
    df$Plans = 'F' & df$Coins == 0 & df$Copay == 0 ~ 0,
    df$Plans %in% c('G', 'H') & !is.na(df$Coins) & !is.na(df$Copay)
        & df$Copy != 0 ~ 0,
    df$Plans %in% c('I', 'J') & df$Coins > df$Copay & df$Copy = 0 ~ 1
    TRUE ~ 0    # default value is zero
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I am reading your 5th condition well, but if you mean that CoinsCopay should be 1 when Copay == 0 & Coins is not NA or 0, you could do with base R:

```
df$CoinsCopay <- ifelse((!is.na(df$Coins) & is.na(df$Copay)) | (!df$Coins %in% c(0,NA) & df$Copay %in% 0), 1, 0)

> df
   Plans Coins Copay CoinsCopay
1      A     0    NA          1
2      B     0    NA          1
3      C    10    NA          1
4      D    NA     0          0
5      E    NA    50          0
6      F     0     0          0
7      G    20    10          0
8      H    40     5          0
9      I    20     0          1
10     J     5     0          1
```